# Is there a way to pass faux terminal input to a program?

Tags: unix, command-line, terminal, automated-tests, command-line-interface

I've begun using [`bats`](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats) heavily to test my shell scripts and command-line executables, regardless of the language or environment they're developed for.

However, a glaring omission at this point, for me, is the ability to test *interactive-terminal* behaviour for command-line programs: the ways that a CLI interface behave when attached to a real user's terminal, as opposed to how they operate when being piped or redirected. (This includes things like real-time interaction, curses-style terminal-size calculations, colour-codes, etcetcetc.)

First off, the simple question: are there simple, UNIX-y ways to pass keystrokes or Terminal events or whatever to a pipe, and can I configure a pipe for which I intend to do so in a way that makes it appear as an interactive terminal to the program?

Second, and more general: is there any software that helps with this problem? Anything from a testing framework to a full-on `phantom`-esque scriptable faux-terminal for testing purposes is welcome, here. (=

Comment: You probably need [expect](http://expect.sf.net)

Comment: Heh. That said, @glennjackman, if you write that up with a bit more information as an actual answer, I might end up accepting it … given that nothing else seems forthcoming …